# Laravel str_replace not replace tag

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem. I have a string:

```
Dear subscribers! We want to provide you with: {followers}.

Thanks very much!
```

I need replace followers on:

```php
$followers = '@id' . implode(',@id', array_pluck($birthdayFollowers, 'id'));

$message->body = str_replace($message->body, '{followers}', $followers);
```

In array `birthdayFollowers` I have id column. In `$message->body` I have a text, which up.

When I do dd `message->body` I get only this:

```
@id11133064,@id346586105
```

Why? I need to get the whole message.

Comment: Try to change order of parameter : `str_replace('{followers'}, $followers, $message->body)`

Answer (score 0):

str_replace except search pattern as first argument, replace as second and subject as third.
It should be `str_replace("{followers}", $followers, $message->body)`

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php